# blueimp jquery fileupload - server related issues

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, file-upload, blueimp

i needed a fileupload-tool in an intranet application i am currently working on and decided to use blueimp's nice piece of work.
on my testing environment (xampp on windows, same versions like the productive environment), everything worked out fine with only using the basic plugin.
after publishing my work to the "real" server, i got errors i have never seen in my testing environment (which is close to identical).
my stuff has to work on IE9-IE11.

i am getting a script error on IE9: "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'files': object is null or undefined"
on IE11, i am getting this error: "SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3."

when i use blueimp's demo-version on the productive environment i am getting the "emtpy file upload result" error.

this is all very strange, because in terms of server versions my testing environment is identical and everything is working fine there.

of course i also checked the directory/file permission settings - everything seems ok.

any suggestions?

```
    $('.fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {
            /* ...... */
            },

    done: function (e, data) {

    /* ...... */    
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            /* ..... */
        });
            }
     });
```